# Why does English use the adjective structure "noun-doing" instead of "doing-noun"?

Tags: adjectives

A similar question is [Using the structure "noun-adjective" as a noun (e.g. "innovation-inclined")](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438633/using-the-structure-noun-adjective-as-a-noun-e-g-innovation-inclined). The structure "noun-done" ("innovation-inclined") makes sense to me, because it is consistent with the normal English order "object be done" ("innovation is inclined to") where the noun is the object, and the subject isn't necessarily clear.

However, "noun-doing" defies the English "subject verb object" order where the noun is the object. It sounds like Japanese "S-O-V" to me. One example is "degree-granting campus" instead of "granting-degree campus", whereas the sentence order is "campus grants degree". Why does such structure exist in English?

Comment: Just because 'that's how it is in English'. The combination "noun-gerund" forms an adjective, and adjectives precede the noun.

Comment: There is undoubtedly a historic reason for this that dates back to Old English (or farther), but modern English speakers aren't going to know this historic reason; they use this order because that's the word order they learned. The structure goes at least as far back as Shakespeare. (ca. 1600): "Hamlet: *What are they that would speak with me?*
Servant: ***Seafaring** men, sir. They say they have letters for you.*"

Comment: And it's much older than Shakespeare. The OED has a citation for *seafaring men* (*safarinde men*) from 1200.

Comment: German has the same order, e.g. *die Holzbearbeitung*, woodworking. So it's a Proto-Germanic thing.

Answer (score 2):

In a noun phrase, modifiers generally precede the noun they modify.
It is more common to say ***a brick wall***, than *a wall of bricks*.

Now with compound adjectives, you need the hyphen to establish a unit modifier as [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/spelling-using-compound-words-guide) explains:

> Compound adjectives are combinations of words that work together to modify a noun—technically, they work as ***unit modifiers***. As unit modifiers, they are *distinguished from other strings of adjectives that may also precede a noun*.
>
> Unit modifiers are mostly hyphenated. ***Hyphens*** not only make it easier for readers to grasp the relationship of the words but also ***aid in avoiding confusion***. For example, the hyphen in
>
> > a call for a more-specialized curriculum
>
> removes any ambiguity as to which the word *more* modifies.

Your question is why within the unit modifier the noun comes before the -ing form of the verb and not the other way round. If you think of compound nouns such as:

> - bird-watching (also spelt birdwatching or bird watching)
> - bee-keeping (same variants available)
> - babysitting

you see that the object of the verb used here in its -ing form comes first, although in a SVO simple sentence, the standard word order would be respected:

> I am watching birds.

This is simply how English works. This is most probably why we say

> degree-granting campus.

The hyphen immediately helps us identify the unit modifier ***degree-granting*** which naturally precedes the noun it modifies. Within the unit modifier, *degree* must precede the word it modifies: it is not just any kind of granting, it is a ***degree-granting*** (that is, *granting of degrees*).

I found an interesting article on [Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/premodifier-grammar-1691527#:%7E:text=%22Premodifying%20elements%20in%20prehead%20position,of%20the%20things%20it%20denotes.) about ***premodification*** which says:

> As noted by Douglas Biber et. al. in *Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English*,2002
>
> > Premodifiers are condensed structures. They use fewer words than postmodifiers to convey roughly the same information. Most adjectival and participial premodifiers can be rephrased as a longer, postmodifying relative clause.

Comment: '... a call for a more-specialized curriculum' is unnecessary, unusual and arguably unacceptable.  '... a call for more-specialized curriculums' will be necessary if not sensibly reworded. // Offhand, 'slow-acting' seems in the necessary order, and compound adjectives from [noun] + [ing-form] don't seem vastly different: the noun qualifies the following ing-form.

Comment: It's worth noting that "watching birds" could also be a noun phrase describing some birds that are observant.

Answer (score 0):

> One example is "degree-granting campus" instead of "granting-degree campus", whereas the sentence order is "campus grants degree". Why does such structure exist in English?

**degree granting campus** = a campus that is contextually associated with the granting of degrees.

**granting** is a verbal noun. [This becomes apparent as there are no adverbs.]

**degree granting** is thus [noun1]+[noun2]

In the same way, **a beer bottle** is [noun1]+[noun2] and means a bottle that is contextually associated with beer. Thus we can say

[noun1]+[noun2] = [noun2] that is contextually associated with [noun1]

We can extend this to [noun1]+[noun2]+[noun3] in "**a beer bottle shape**" = A [noun3 =shape] that is contextually associated with [noun2=bottle] that is contextually associated with [noun1=beer]

{degree granting} = the granting that is contextually associated with degrees.

Now we have a third noun "campus"

**degree granting campus** = **the campus** that is contextually associated with **granting** that is contextually associated with **degrees**.